Синонимизировать метки slickjs и slider-slick.js
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

slick.js (369 вопроса) описание есть
slider-slick.js (54 вопроса) описания нет

Основная метка - slick.js

updating post history, 61 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 54 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 27 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'slider-slick.js': [slider-slick.js] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 397
tag remapping of [slick.js] and [slider-slick.js] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

